# Limitar acceso de usuario en una app de Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estoy creando una app con ionic y quiero que, cuando el usuario **no** esté logueado y se dirija a una página que no sea el login o el registro, esta lo lleve al login. En caso que el usuario quiera ir al registro, que la app se lo permita.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, fromState){
    if(!UserFactory.isLoggedIn() && (toState.name !== 'login' || toState.name !== 'register') ){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

Pero el mismo me genera un loop, alguna solución?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una función con una promesa que compruebe si está autentificado el usuario y si no, que redirija al login.

Después, en cada estado que se requiera un usuario logueado resuelves esa función. Por ejemplo:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html',
      controller: 'homeCtrl as home',
      resolve: {
        authenticate: authenticate
      }
    })
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'components/login/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl as login'
  });
  // Además, cuando el usuario hace login almaceno su token en el localstorage.
  // Al iniciar la aplicación si no hay token es que no hay usuario logueado,
  // por lo que redirijo directamente al login.

  if (!(typeof window.localStorage.token !== 'undefined' &&
      window.localStorage.token !== null)) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
  } else {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }
```

Siendo mi función de autentificar la siguiente:

```
function authenticate($ionicPlatform, $q, Auth) {
// Auth es mi propio servicio que se encarga del login/logout.
  if (Auth.isLogged()) {
    return $q.resolve();
  } else {
    Auth.logout();
    return $q.reject();
  }
}
```

y en *Auth.logout()* tengo un `$state.go('login');` al final para dirigir al login.

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambia la condicional. Pon un `and` en lugar de un `or`

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, fromState){
    if(!UserFactory.isLoggedIn() && toState.name !== 'login' && toState.name !== 'register'){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

De la forma anterior si el usuario no está logueado y el estado es `'login'` el resultado de la comparacion sería el siguiente

```
// no logueado estado login
if(true && (false || true)){
     // Esto es true y vuelve a login
}

// no logueado estado registro
if(true && (true || false)){
     // Esto es true y vuelve a login
}

// no logueado otro estado
if(true && (true || true)){
     // Esto es true y vuelve a login
}
```

De la forma que te pongo

```
// no logueado estado login
if(true && false && true)){
     // Esto es false y no hace nada
}

// no logueado estado registro
if(true && true && false)){
     // Esto es false y no hace nada
}

// no logueado otro estado
if(true && true && true)){
     // Esto es true y vuelve a login
}
```

Comment: mmm, sigue generandome un bucle, tal vez es error mio. 

Puedes ejemplificarme tu respuesta, con el código de ionic, tal vez lo estoy interpretando mal, muchas gracias!

Comment: @user3042194 Por la respuesta eliminada veo que trataste de poner la condicion tres veces. Solo debes escribirlo una vez como te lo puse al principio. Lo que puse debajo es una explicación de lo que tenías antes con lo que tendrías ahora si usas el código que te dejé y el resultado de las comparaciones. No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion es algo como esto:

```
        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            cache: false,
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "pagina.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
            onEnter: function($state, Auth){
                if(!UserFactory.isLoggedIn()){

                   $state.go('login');

                }
            }                
        })
```

Asi consigo que antes de entrar vaya al login, habia probado lo que comentais pero me daba errores y con esta opcion me va bien.

Que conste que yo estoy empezando y no soy ningun guru asi que si hay algun error no seais muy duros :)

Comment: Genial! Llegue a la misma solución, y creo que es lo mas acertado a nivel conceptual. 

Gracias!